# python struct.pack equivalent for pure javascript

Tags: javascript, python, binary

Unable find any specific pure javascript lib to implement below python syntax.

below is python syntax.

```
result = struct.pack('<i', 6).hex()
```

Comment: What is `struct` here? Please specify all the necessary details

Comment: Try to look at https://github.com/lyngklip/structjs.

Answer (score 0):

there are no pure js libraries which are similar to this feature but I have discovered one third party library [python-struct](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-struct) which does the exact operations of python's struct have a look.
A sample from the website.
`const struct = require('python-struct'); k=struct.pack(">f",49.9);`
the out put will be a js buffer object